# SQL - Adherence Report - How to account for time intervals outside of an employee's schedule?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to build an adherence report in SQL.  I'm comparing an employee's schedule with what they actually did that day.  At any point in time, their current activity either matches their schedule, or it does not.

Using an INNER JOIN, I am able to compare all time intervals that overlap.  My problem is accounting for the intervals that do not overlap.

Example: You are scheduled to start at 10AM, but you log in at 9:30 AM. I can account for the interval starting at 10AM, but not the 30 minutes beforehand.

In my example code below, I have Actual activity (a) and Scheduled activity (s).  Each activity also has a type that is compared to see if they match.
(time constraints, duration, and actual adherence are handled in the query, but I omitted them for simplicity)

```
SELECT a.ID
     , a.Start
     , a.End
     , a.Type
     , s.Start
     , s.End
     , s.Type

FROM a
INNER JOIN s ON a.ID = s.ID AND a.Start < s.End AND a.END > s.Start
```

This code generates rows that have overlapping time intervals. I then use a CASE WHEN to generate intervals and compare data. The first row may look like:

```
45 | 9:30 AM | 10:58 AM | Available | 10:00 AM  |  11:00 AM  |  Available
```

The first interval pulled from this would be 10:00 AM - 10:58 AM (further SQL coding pulls the later start time and earlier end time). I need to find a means to account for that 9:30 AM to 10:00 AM interval. I don't have a row in the results, and they are both "Start" times, which complicates deriving the interval.

This is a very specific question and I've had trouble finding related information online.  Any assistance you can provide will be appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results in a *text table* format would be a big help.